# Django - How to redirect back to search page and include query terms?

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

My pages/views are structured as follows:

```
index.html => search_results.html => object_details.html,
in which user can make a POST request in object_details.html.
```

I am trying to redirect back to **search_results.html** after the POST request, but also keep both query strings.

The url of search results shows as follows, and can have 1 or both queries made:

```
www.example.com/search-results/?search_post=xxxxx&search_author=xxxxx
```

The closest I am able to get what I want is using:

```
return redirect(reverse('search-results') + '?' + 'search_post={{search_post}}'+'&'+'search_author={{search_author}}')
```

however this would actually show "**{{search_post}}**" and "**{{search_author}}**" in each of the 2 fields of the search form in **search_results.html**,
and would return the url:

**[www.example.com/search-results/?search_post=%7B%7Bsearch_post%7D&search_author=%7B%7Bsearch_author%7D%7D](http://www.example.com/search-results/?search_post=%7B%7Bsearch_post%7D&search_author=%7B%7Bsearch_author%7D%7D)**

Also, my search_results view has the following:

```
search_post = request.GET.get('search_post')

search_author = request.GET.get('search_author')
```

How can I do this? Tried using answers for similar questions but yet to figure it out.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just make an error with quotes. You cannot use same syntax as django template. Try using f-string:

```py
return redirect(reverse('search-results') + f"?search_post={search_post}&search_author={search_author}")
```

Documentation about string: https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/

Ok after your answer, I made a refactoring your view. You can reuse the `results` for the next filtering at each step of your form processing in fact. And your, I think, your chaining `elif` was not good and make error.

```py
def search_results(request, *args, **kwargs):

    search_post = request.GET.get('search_post', '')
    search_author = request.GET.get('search_author', '')

    results = Post.objects.all()
    if search_author != '':
        results = results.filter(city__icontains=search_author.strip())
    
    if search_post != '':
        results = results.filter(post__icontains=search_post.strip())

    context = {
        'results': results,
        'search_post': search_post,
        'search_author': search_author,
    }

    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

Comment: This gave me a similar result to what I got earlier, filled the 2 fields on the search for with "None" on each field. How can I get it to fill the form with the initial search query?

Comment: if you post only little parts of your code, we cannot help you more. I fix the only bad things you do in the code you have posted

Comment: I added the full code as a separate answer, thank you

Comment: @PolarBear ok i added some other fixes

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def search_results(request, *args, **kwargs):

    search_post = request.GET.get('search_post')
    search_author = request.GET.get('search_author')

    if search_author and not search_post:
        results = Post.objects.distinct().filter(
            (Q(city__icontains=search_author.strip())))
    
    elif search_post and not search_author:
        results = Post.objects.distinct().filter(
            (Q_post__icontains=search_post.strip()))

    elif search_post and search_author:
        results = Post.objects.distinct().filter(
            (Q_post__icontains=search_post.strip())
            )
            .filter(
            (Q(city__icontains=search_author.strip())
            )
            )
    
    elif search_post and search_author == None:
        results = Post.objects.all().distinct()
        return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'results':results, 'search_post':search_post, 'search_author':search_author})
    
    else:
        results = Post.objects.all().distinct()

    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'results':results, 'search_post':search_post, 'search_author':search_author})



def post_details(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post_owner = post.owner
    search_post = request.GET.get('search_post')
    search_author = request.GET.get('search_author')

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        saved = Submission.objects.filter(post=post, owner=request.user)
        if saved and request.method == 'POST':
            return render (request, 'post_details.html', {'post':post, 'saved':saved})


        if request.method == 'POST':
            instance = Submission(post=post, post_owner=post_owner,owner=request.user)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('post-details', pk=post.id)


    else:
        return render (request, 'post_details.html', {'post':post})
    
    return render (request, 'post_details.html', {'post':post, 'saved':saved})
```